# Showing $f(z)$ is constant if $g(z)=\sqrt{f(z)}$ is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Concerning an entire function $f$, one is presented with the information that $g(z)=\sqrt{f(z)}$ also defines an entire function.  Show that $f$ must be a constant function.

I'm not sure how to approach this.  I do know that $\sqrt{z}$ is not analytic along $(-\infty,0]$.  This means that $g(z)$ is not entire along $(-\infty,0]$.

So here is what I have so far.  Since $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic only on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ we know that $f(z) \not\in (-\infty,0]$ since $g(z)$ is analytic.  Knowing this we have $g'(z)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{f(z)}}f'(z)$.  It follows that $f(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$.  Then $\sqrt{f(\mathbb{C})}=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \,| \,Re(z)>0\}.$  I'm not sure about the other half of the plane.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your question. Note that both $g(z)=z$ and $f(z)=z^2$ are entire, but $g(z)^2=f(z)$. The "function" $\sqrt{z}$ is not well-defined on the entire complex plane. It's true that you can define a branch of it on the slit plane $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus(-\infty,0]$, but that's not unique -- for example, you can also define a branch on $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: If you are told that the range of $f$ omits the negative real axis, then the little Picard theorem says that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Ah, I currently do not have the power of little Picard's theorem.

Comment: As Michael Weiss said, the statement is false. Another example: the function $f(z)=e^z$ is entire, and so its square root $e^{z/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to rephrase the question. First, though, let me note the objections to the phrasing as given. Take for example $g(z)=z$ and $f(z)=z^2$. Then $g(z)^2=f(z)$, but both $f$ and $g$ are non-constant entire functions. The equation $g(z)=\sqrt{f(z)}$ has no meaning until one choses a branch of the square-root function.

Here's the rephrasing:

> Suppose $f$ is an entire function whose range omits the negative real axis, i.e., $f(\mathbb{C})\subseteq \mathbb{C}\smallsetminus (-\infty,0]$. Show that $f$ is constant. Hint: we can define a single-valued analytic branch of the square-root function on $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus (-\infty,0]$, and using this branch we can define $g(z)=\sqrt{f(z)}$, which must also be entire.

As you've already figured out, the range of $g(z)$ will lie in the right half-plane $\{z: \Re(z)>0\}$. Now compose $g$ with a fractional linear transformation that maps the right-half plane to the interior of the unit disk, say $h(z)=L(g(z))$. What does this tell us about $h$ -- what property does $h$ have? And given that property, what result then tells us that $h$ must be constant?

Incidentally, the usual proof of the famous little Picard theorem (an entire function whose range omits two values is constant) uses the same proof strategy, but replaces the square root with the "inverse" of the elliptic modular function $\lambda$. Now, $\lambda$ doesn't have a single-valued inverse, but one can define a single-valued branch of $\lambda^{-1}(f(z))$.

Comment: Is there a proof of this theorem that doesn't use linear fractional transformations? I'm stuck at this.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid LFTs?

Comment: I haven't covered LFTs this far, so naturally, I was thinking of a proof that didn't rely on LFTs.

Comment: In that case, probably the simplest proof is to show by an explicit computation that the map $z\mapsto\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ sends the right half plane to the interior of the unit disk.

Comment: Basicslly using a LFT, again. I couldn't come up/motivate the use of any such map as well, though. Hence, I was stuck.

Comment: You could also use the map $z\mapsto e^{-z}$.

Comment: How would that allow us to solve problem? Currently, I'm having trouble when/how to use auxiliary functions to aid in solving problems.